# Solve $dy/dx = \sin(x+y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u(x)=x+y(x)$, which implies $\frac{du(x)}{dx}=1+\frac{dy(x)}{dx}$. The equation becomes separable : $$ \frac{du}{\sin(u)+1}=dx \iff \tan(u)-\frac{1}{\cos(u)}=x+C $$

This last equation seems to be a transcendental equation with no direct solution. However, the solutions are $y=-x-\pi /2+2k\pi$, or $\sin(x+y)-1=(x+C)\cos(x+y)$ or $y=-x-2\arctan(1+\frac{2}{x+C})+2k\pi$. Except for the first solution, I cannot manage to find those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is the half-angle identity
$$
\tan \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}.
$$
Substituting $\theta\rightarrow \pi/2 - u$ gives
$$
\tan\left(\frac{u}{2} -\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\sin u - 1}{\cos u} = \tan u - \frac{1}{\cos u},
$$
which is what you got from variable separation. Doing the algebra then leads to the solution
$$
y = 2\tan^{-1}(x + C) - x + \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi.
$$

Comment: How do you solve the equation $tan(u)-1/cos(u)=x+C$ for $u$? The algebra is not clear to me.

Comment: You use $\tan u - 1/\cos u = \tan(u/2 + \pi/4)$, then take $\tan^{-1}$ of both sides.

Comment: Great answer. However, the solution is $y=-x-2arctan(1+\frac{2}{x+C})+2k\pi$. How do you turn $
y = 2\tan^{-1}(x + C) - x + \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi
$ into this ? I tried but I don't see how