# Solve $\frac{\operatorname dy}{\operatorname dx}=\sin(x+y)$ (again)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As you can see, I asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4887239/solve-dy-dx-sinxy/4887259#4887259), and got a nice answer from the user eyeballfrog. Unfortunately, his answer, namely

$$
y = 2\tan^{-1}(x + C) - x + \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi,
$$

doesn't match to the one in my textbook, *i.e.*

$$y=-2\tan^{-1}(1+\frac{2}{x+C})-x+2k\pi$$

I have tried it again with his tip multiple times this week but I didn't manage to get the textbook result.

Comment: Note that the values $C$ and $k$ won't be the same for the two answers. Is it possible these two formula can be made equal?

Comment: If we use $C_1,k_1$ for your answer and $C_2,k_2$ for the book answer, and we assume the functions are equal, then we get $k_2=k_1+1$ by considering the limit limit of $y+x$ as $x\to\infty.$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't see how I could get the textbook answer from the user's answer just by setting $k_2=k_1+1$.

Comment: You can't, that's just the start, not the finish. I don't even know if they are equivalent. I said **if they are equal** then $k_2=k_1+1.$

Comment: Did you check if both solutions satisfy the differential equation?

Comment: @Digitallis Because managing to start from the user's solution and finish to the textbook solution might simply be an algebra problem. If it bothers you that much I can delete this tag

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok, sorry for the confusion, thank you !

Comment: @MartinR good point, I'll do this right away, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: ```\operatorname``` is not the right way to typeset $\mathrm dy$. What should be used is ```\mathrm{d}y```.

Comment: The functions have different domains so, strictly speaking, they are not the same. On intervals where they are both defined, you may check they have the same derivative, hence they would differ by a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, upto a fixed multiple of $\pi$ (depending on where $x$ lies), the following holds.
$$\tan^{-1}(u)+\tan^{-1}\left(1+\frac2{u-1}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{u+1+\frac2{u-1}}{1-u\left(1+\frac2{u-1}\right)}\right)$$
The fraction inside nicely simplifies
$$\frac{u+1+\frac2{u-1}}{1-u\left(1+\frac2{u-1}\right)}=\frac{u^2-1+2}{(u-1)-u(u+1)}=\frac{u^2+1}{-(u^2+1)}=-1$$
Therefore,
$$2\tan^{-1}(x+C)+\frac{\pi}{2}=2m\pi-2\tan^{-1}\left(1+\frac2{x+C-1}\right)$$
This shows that the two solutions are equal for suitable relabelling of $C$ and $k$.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Can the downvoter explain..?